# Can you migrate an Azure cloud service to another data center and maintain the VIP?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have a Cloud Service running in the East US data center. Could I migrate the Cloud Service to the West US data center, but maintain the same VIP? How would you go about doing this?

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.  The VIP is persisted for the lifetime of the deployment.  So, you'd creating a new Cloud Service in West US, and that service would have a VIP that is different from what was in your East US deployment.

Comment: The answer above is correct, what I do is publish my project to Azure in staging if it works I change the CNAME record in the web registrar and have little down time...if you have stateless services this works easier.  This works for sites that can have a small maintenance window or a little down time...there are more sophisticated approaches with fault update domains (but it also costs more as you are running 4+ replicas of all your services).  IIS 7.x also has features to mitigate this.

Comment: The reason I wanted to maintain the VIP over multiple deployments is because I have more than 10 domains pointing to this application. Not only that, but these domains are managed outside of my control, and updating them all with a new VIP is not practical. I have set up something called a [Traffic Manager Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsazuretrafficmanager) however, this doesn't give a VIP so updating domain A records to point to the policy isn't possible. Still looking for a permanent solution.